# Using has_one with condition to find related object, but how do you create the related object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have an Account model with the following :

```
has_one :primary_user, :class_name => "User", :conditions => "role = 'primary_user'"
```

So @account.primary_user looks for a user with a role of primary_user.

When creating a new account, I want to be able to create a new primary_user. What is the "Rails way" to do that ?

Do I need to create a primary_user= method?

Here is my create form ..

```
<%= semantic_form_for @account do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :account_name %>

    <%= f.semantic_fields_for :primary_user do |user| %>
      <%= user.input :email %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

If I submit this form I get

ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (User(#2159789500) expected, got ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#2159703820)):

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Little cleaner:

```
has_one :primary_user, :class_name => "User", :conditions => { :role => "primary_user" }
```

Then straight solution:

```
<%= semantic_form_for @account do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :account_name %>

    <%= f.semantic_fields_for :primary_user, primary_user || build_primary_user do |user| %>
      <%= user.input :email %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But I suggest you to add this into new action in controller

```
@account.build_primary_user
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this would add the user with the role "primary_user", would it ?

Comment: After submitting from it will. Or you need to add user befor submitting?

Comment: @Batkins `@account.build_primary_user`

Comment: @account.build_primary_user, does not create a user with the role "primary_user" so my question is what is the best way to handle that?

Comment: It doesn't create but initialize new user with role "primary_user". Ussualy you don't need to create new user before form submition. But if you really need it: `@account.create_primary_user` will help you

Answer (score 0):

This builds on top of what @fl00r says in his post... I agree the proper place to make build the objects is in the controller.  In the `new` action on your `AccountsController`, you just need to add a line like this:

`@account.primary_user ||= @account.build_primary_user`

So your `new` action would look something like this (plus anything extra you added):

```
def new
  @account = Account.new
  @account.primary_user ||= @account.build_primary_user
end
```

Then your code for the create form should work as is.